# Stored Procedure showing error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am having this stored procedure in MySQL. But it is showing error and Not specifying what exactly error is.

my stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE 'spmselfinformation'
(
Sid int,
SCompany_Name varchar(45),
SAddress1 varchar(100),
SAddress2 varchar(100),
SCity varchar(45),
SPincode int,
SContact_Person varchar(45),
STelephone int,
STelefax int,
SEmail_Address varchar(45),
SReport_Signature varchar(100),
SState_Sale_Taxno varchar(45),
SCentral_Taxno varchar(45),
SLic1 varchar(45),
SDate1 as Datetime,
SLic2 varchar(45),
SDate2 as Datetime,
SDate_Of_Entry as Datetime,
SLic3 varchar(45),
SDate3 as Datetime,
STTIN_No varchar(45),
SVATTIN_No varchar(45),
SLBT_No varchar(45),
STerms_and_Conditions1 varchar(100),
STerms_and_Conditions2 varchar(100),
STerms_and_Conditions3 varchar(100),
STerms_and_Conditions4 varchar(100),
SLogo_File_Name varchar(45),
SWebsite varchar(100),
SOpen_Hours varchar(45),
SNote varchar(100),
SFlag int
)
BEGIN
if SFlag=1 then
INSERT INTO  tbl_selfinformation (id,Company_Name,Address1,Address2,City,Pincode,Contact_Person,Telephone,Telefax,Email_Address,Report_Signature,State_Sale_Taxno,Central_Taxno,Lic1,Date1,Lic2,Date2,Date_Of_Entry,Lic3,Date3,TTIN_No,VATTIN_No,LBT_No,Terms_and_Conditions1,Terms_and_Conditions2,Terms_and_Conditions3,Terms_and_Conditions4,Logo_File_Name,Website,Open_Hours,Note) VALUES(Sid,SCompany_Name,SAddress1,SAddress2,SCity,SPincode,SContact_Person,STelephone,STelefax,SEmail_Address,SReport_Signature,SState_Sale_Taxno,SCentral_Taxno,SLic1,SDate1,SLic2,SDate2,SDate_Of_Entry,SLic3,SDate3,STTIN_No,SVATTIN_No,SLBT_No,STerms_and_Conditions1,STerms_and_Conditions2,STerms_and_Conditions3,STerms_and_Conditions4,SLogo_File_Name,SWebsite,SOpen_Hours,SNote);
END if;
IF SFlag =2 then
UPDATE  tbl_selfinformation SET id=Sid,Company_Name=SCompany_Name,Address1=SAddress1,Address2=SAddress2,City=SCity,Pincode=SPincode,Contact_Person=SContact_Person,Telephone=STelephone,Telefax=STelefax,Email_Address=SEmail_Address,Report_Signature=SReport_Signature,State_Sale_Taxno=SState_Sale_Taxno,Central_Taxno=SCentral_Taxno,Lic1=SLic1,Date1=SDate1,Lic2=SLic2,Date2=SDate2,Date_Of_Entry=SDate_Of_Entry,Lic3=SLic3,Date3=SDate3,TTIN_No=STTIN_No,VATTIN_No=SVATTIN_No,LBT_No=SLBT_No,Terms_and_Conditions1=STerms_and_Conditions1,Terms_and_Conditions2=STerms_and_Conditions2,Terms_and_Conditions3=STerms_and_Conditions3,Terms_and_Conditions4=STerms_and_Conditions4,Logo_File_Name=SLogo_File_Name,Website=SWebsite,Open_Hours=SOpen_Hours,Note=SNote;
END if;
END
```

it is showing this screen.
[image]

I am not able to figure it out what exactly I am doing wrong. anyone can help me.

**EDIT 1**

this is my table definition

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `invntory_system`.`tbl_selfinformation`;
CREATE TABLE  `invntory_system`.`tbl_selfinformation` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `Company_Name` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Address1` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `Address2` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `City` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Pincode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `Contact_Person` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Telephone` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `Telefax` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `Email_Address` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Report_Signature` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `State_Sale_Taxno` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Central_Taxno` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Lic1` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Date1` datetime default NULL,
  `Lic2` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Date2` datetime default NULL,
  `Date_Of_Entry` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `Lic3` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Date3` datetime default NULL,
  `TTIN_No` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `VATTIN_No` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `LBT_No` varchar(45) NOT NULL default '',
  `Terms_and_Conditions1` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Terms_and_Conditions2` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Terms_and_Conditions3` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Terms_and_Conditions4` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Logo_File_Name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Website` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Open_Hours` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Note` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Self Information';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few issues in the code: the name of the procedure should not be enclosed in single-quotes. The datetime variables should be declared as just `datetime` not `as datetime` and finally I think you need to change the delimiter from semi-colon so the "fixed" script that should work would look like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE spmselfinformation
(
Sid int,
SCompany_Name varchar(45),
SAddress1 varchar(100),
SAddress2 varchar(100),
SCity varchar(45),
SPincode int,
SContact_Person varchar(45),
STelephone int,
STelefax int,
SEmail_Address varchar(45),
SReport_Signature varchar(100),
SState_Sale_Taxno varchar(45),
SCentral_Taxno varchar(45),
SLic1 varchar(45),
SDate1  Datetime,
SLic2 varchar(45),
SDate2  Datetime,
SDate_Of_Entry  Datetime,
SLic3 varchar(45),
SDate3  Datetime,
STTIN_No varchar(45),
SVATTIN_No varchar(45),
SLBT_No varchar(45),
STerms_and_Conditions1 varchar(100),
STerms_and_Conditions2 varchar(100),
STerms_and_Conditions3 varchar(100),
STerms_and_Conditions4 varchar(100),
SLogo_File_Name varchar(45),
SWebsite varchar(100),
SOpen_Hours varchar(45),
SNote varchar(100),
SFlag int
)
BEGIN
IF SFlag = 1 THEN 
INSERT INTO  tbl_selfinformation (id,Company_Name,Address1,Address2,City,Pincode,Contact_Person,Telephone,Telefax,Email_Address,Report_Signature,State_Sale_Taxno,Central_Taxno,Lic1,Date1,Lic2,Date2,Date_Of_Entry,Lic3,Date3,TTIN_No,VATTIN_No,LBT_No,Terms_and_Conditions1,Terms_and_Conditions2,Terms_and_Conditions3,Terms_and_Conditions4,Logo_File_Name,Website,Open_Hours,Note) VALUES(Sid,SCompany_Name,SAddress1,SAddress2,SCity,SPincode,SContact_Person,STelephone,STelefax,SEmail_Address,SReport_Signature,SState_Sale_Taxno,SCentral_Taxno,SLic1,SDate1,SLic2,SDate2,SDate_Of_Entry,SLic3,SDate3,STTIN_No,SVATTIN_No,SLBT_No,STerms_and_Conditions1,STerms_and_Conditions2,STerms_and_Conditions3,STerms_and_Conditions4,SLogo_File_Name,SWebsite,SOpen_Hours,SNote);
END IF;
IF SFlag = 2 THEN
UPDATE  tbl_selfinformation SET id=Sid,Company_Name=SCompany_Name,Address1=SAddress1,Address2=SAddress2,City=SCity,Pincode=SPincode,Contact_Person=SContact_Person,Telephone=STelephone,Telefax=STelefax,Email_Address=SEmail_Address,Report_Signature=SReport_Signature,State_Sale_Taxno=SState_Sale_Taxno,Central_Taxno=SCentral_Taxno,Lic1=SLic1,Date1=SDate1,Lic2=SLic2,Date2=SDate2,Date_Of_Entry=SDate_Of_Entry,Lic3=SLic3,Date3=SDate3,TTIN_No=STTIN_No,VATTIN_No=SVATTIN_No,LBT_No=SLBT_No,Terms_and_Conditions1=STerms_and_Conditions1,Terms_and_Conditions2=STerms_and_Conditions2,Terms_and_Conditions3=STerms_and_Conditions3,Terms_and_Conditions4=STerms_and_Conditions4,Logo_File_Name=SLogo_File_Name,Website=SWebsite,Open_Hours=SOpen_Hours,Note=SNote;
END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```